# Flink JobManager dies due to checkpoint failures

Tags: apache-flink

I recently migrated our Flink from `1.9.0` to `1.11.1` without HA Job cluster. I am facing the following error which is causing `JobManager` to fail after every 5 minutes and Flink jobs stuck in these restart loop via AWS ECS.

It used to work in Flink 1.9.0 after upgrade `1.11.1` it does not. Since I don't have JM HA, I generate fixed `--job-id` for each flink job instead of default id 00000000000. I am new to Flink.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Could not finalize the pending checkpoint
5.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.completePendingCheckpoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:837)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.receiveAcknowledgeMessage(CheckpointCoordinator.java:756)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.lambda$acknowledgeCheckpoint$9(JobMaster.java:676)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: 's3://data/flink/checkpoints/<unique_job_id>/chk-5/_metadata'
already exists
```

Comment: Could you clarify if `<unique_job_id>` is actually two folders? It's strange that there is no attempt id.

Comment: @ArvidHeise No unique job-id is Flink supported UUID w/o dash

Comment: Note: there was way too much code formatting here. The names of pieces of software should be treated as proper nouns, and thus they are capitalised. That's it - no bolding, code formatting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are re-using the same job id across multiple runs and this leads to collisions. If you are not using HA then you should always generate a unique job id for each job run/job submission. The easiest way to do it is to generate a random id. You only need to fix the job id if you want to recover a job run from the state stored in the HA stores.

Comment: If I use random job id then in case of failure and restart I lose checkpoints how does it recover and restore kafka offsets? This is why I use fixed job id so that in case of failure it can recover/read checkpoints from same job id folder. I could see this in Flink UI. If I use random job id it never recovers offsets from checkpoints. Please guide.

Comment: Are you saying we cant recover offsets from checkpoints w/o HA?

Comment: Yes, if you want to tolerate JobManager failures, then you need to enable HA. W/o HA you can only recover from Task failures or TaskManager failures. But if the JobManager is restarted, then you cannot recover the job.

Comment: OK w/o JM HA with fixed job id across multiple runs used to work fine for me in Flink 1.9.0 including JM restart and recovery. It stopped working after Flink 1.11.1 upgrade. Will it work in Flink 1.11.2? Is this because checkpoint completion notification related changes done in 1.11.1 https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/9dce8f0dcf68492240933a74dbce760ae25ce07f?

Comment: Not sure why it worked with Flink 1.9.0, but this was never officially a feature. Hence, I don't think that it will change between 1.11.1 and 1.11.2.